BSS138 level shifter - blocking current flow when high-side supply is not connected?
I've got a board designed which has 5 BSS138 MOSFETs used as level shifters between 3.3 V and 5 V logic. There are various other components on both the 3.3 V and 5 V sides of the boards, and the two supplies are independent (the board is designed to be inserted into the path between two devices, each of which supply one power rail and will have a common GND).
While the board works fine as it is, there is one issue that I'm not thrilled about. If only the 3.3 V power rail is connected, and the 5 V power rail is not connected, and the low-side input of the BSS138 is not driven to GND, then power 'leaks' through the BSS138 and the 5 V side of the board gets power at somewhere between 1.5-1.8 V, with very low current available... but it's enough to (weakly) light up the 5 V power LED, which will confuse the user as they haven't connected the 5 V power rail and the LED is supposed to tell them when they have successfully done that!
The schematic is on CircuitLab Schematic dq865x354b4w, and DC simulation confirms that the voltage at 'TP' that I'd prefer not to be there.

What would be a simple method to ensure that the the BSS138 doesn't supply power to the high side of the circuit unless the 5 V power rail is connected? Of the five BSS138s on this board, one has an active-low low-side 'IN' driven by an MCU digital I/O pin, two have active-high low-side 'IN' driven by off-board UART outputs, and two have active-high high-side 'IN' driven by on-board UART outputs.

The reason this happens is the body-diode in the MOSFET - this is an intrinsic diode whose anode is the source, and cathode is the drain.
The simplest way to prevent this current from back-flowing to the un-powered 5V rail is to place an additional diode in series with the pull-up resistor on the 5V side (anode to +5V, cathode to R2 in your diagram). This will block the current from flowing the "wrong way" through the pull-up resistor.
Any low-leakage diode will do, e.g. a 1N4148 is a common jellybean part. A Schottky diode would be preferred for its low Vf so as not to impact the high logic level too much.

I would also consider placing something like a 100k resistor from 5V to GND if there isn't already some form of load, just to make sure any reverse leakage current through the diode shunts to GND rather than slowly charging any capacitors on the 5V rail.

Note that this won't prevent the 3.3V leaking onto the HV side IO pin - there will still be a 3.3V logic high present. There isn't an awful lot you can do about this.
If you are using it as a unidirectional level shifter, the diode could be placed instead in series with the MOSFET on the HV side (cathode to drain, anode to IO). This would allow the level shifter to still work for Low to High transfer, but would prevent it working for High to Low transfer.

Thanks! There is a load on the 5V side (four SN74LVC2G53 analog multiplexers, and of course the power LED), and some 100n bypass caps for those muxes.

The simplest solution may be to configure the transistor common-source, which has the disadvantages of being uni-directional, and inverting, but it's easy to overlook, and I mention it only for completeness:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It will still perform level translation, to and from any levels you choose. As shown, a 0V/+3.3V input will produce a +5V/0V output, but IN and OUT are isolated. There's no way for anything on the output side to sink current from the input.

While the question asks about using a MOSFET as a level shifter, there are dedicated ICs for performing level shifting which support "Partial power down (Ioff)" as a feature to prevent current backflow when the IC is powered off.
For possible devices from TI look at Voltage translators & level shifters for those with "Partial power down (Ioff)" as a feature.
The TXB0106 6-Bit Bidirectional Level-Shifting and Voltage Translator
With Auto-Direction Sensing and ±15-kV ESD Protection could be a candidate for the circuit in the question. Features from the datasheet:

Supports 3.3 V to 5 V translation:

1.2 V to 3.6 V on A Port and 1.65 to 5.5 V on B Port (VCCA≤ VCCB)


Protection against only one side being powered:


VCC Isolation Feature – If Either VCC Input Is at GND, All Outputs Are in the High-Impedance State
This device is fully specified for partial-power-down applications using Ioff. The Ioff circuitry disables the outputs, preventing damaging current backflow through the device when it is powered down.



Level shifts 6 bits, which is sufficient for the 5 signals in the question.

While the question doesn't specify the maximum frequency of the signals to be level-shifted, the TXB0106 datasheet Operating Characteristics section shows a frequency of 10 MHz.

Thanks! In this application the signals are 2400bps UART, so very low frequency.

This will actually be a simpler design: fewer parts and lower cost. The 'extra bit' will be used to signal the MCU that the 5V supply is present so it can control the OE of the level translator IC. Thanks again!

And finally. the design got even simpler. 4 of the 5 channels referenced in the original question are UART lines, the 5th was a control signal for putting them into or out of high-Z (3-state) mode.
In the end the SN74AHCT125 was a perfect fit; four channels, unidirectional, 5V power supply but TTL-compatible inputs (so 3.3V on the input side is acceptable), and 3-state outputs. Since the OE inputs are also 3.3V compatible, the 5th level shifter was no longer necessary.
